# Simple Example for JANUS WebRTC Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, webrtc, janus

I want to create a video streaming app using Janus.

I setup Janus gateway which is working very well

I wan to setup one way live streaming one-to-many. [Screen Sharing Test](https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/screensharingtest.html) quite similar what i want but i need webcam access instead of screen Share. How can I achieve this. I have very limited knowledge in JavaScript. I want to integrate this in PHP based application. Screen share test script works fine in my application. I gone through [documentation](https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/docs/videoroom.html) but its going over my head.

here is [screen share script](https://github.com/meetecho/janus-gateway/blob/master/html/screensharingtest.js)

Could anyone please guide me how can I achieve above.

Comment: perhaps putting a few code snippets of what you have done. if it is too big, like a project, may be put it in a public repo and link it here would help you attract answers faster. Right now, the question is simply too generic. you might still get some responses but it will be easier if there were more details.

Comment: @jay thanks for your valuable response. I added the script link... i think it might be helpful

Comment: excellent. i am no javascript expert and was primarily helping you make a better question. now wait and watch for the community to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a quick hack...

Just change

```
capture = "screen";
```

to

```
capture = "true";
```

it may work what actually you are looking for. but not the complete solution.

If there should be simple example really that might be helpful for lot people.

any how Happy Coding